# How can I plot two lines from different CSVs with plotly in Python?

Tags: python, csv

I want to plot the data from two different csv files (same column names, though) using Plotly in colab. To plot one csv I currently have:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

a1 = ('/content/a1.csv')
a2 = ('/content/a2.csv')
b1 = ('/content/b1.csv')
b2 = ('/content/b2.csv')

a1_df = pd.read_csv(a1)
a1_graph = px.line(a1_df, x = 'timestamp', y = 'raw_1', title='a1')
a1_graph.show()
```

But is it possible to plot two csvs in the same px.line function?

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate the dataframes together and separate the lines using the color kwarg.

```py
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

a1 = ('/content/a1.csv')
a2 = ('/content/a2.csv')
b1 = ('/content/b1.csv')
b2 = ('/content/b2.csv')

dfList = []

a1_df = pd.read_csv(a1)
a1_df['file'] = 'a1'
dfList.append(a1_df)

a2_df = pd.read_csv(a2)
a2_df['file'] = 'a2'
dfList.append(a2_df)

b1_df = pd.read_csv(b1)
b1_df['file'] = 'b1'
dfList.append(b1_df)

b2_df = pd.read_csv(b2)
b2_df['file'] = 'b2'
dfList.append(b2_df)

df = pd.concat(dfList, axis=1)

a1_graph = px.line(df, x = 'timestamp', y = 'raw_1', color = 'file', title='all files')
a1_graph.show()
```

Comment: I'm new to Python. Am I supposed to replace 'file' with some directory? If it's meant to be "as is," I'm getting an error: ValueError: ```The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().```

Comment: @ShaumDebnath. No, "file" was just a column name. So when the dataframes are concatenated into 1 long dataframe, there is an extra column to indicate the source dataframe. This can then be used in plotly to separate the lines.

Comment: @ShaumDebnath maybe if you edit your question with a working example with some sample data, it'll be easier for me to test it.